# Disallowed Key Characters Error in my code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is the code which give that error.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date();
var date = d.toLocaleString();

 var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?date"+date,true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is php code.

```
<?php

$date = $_GET['date'];

 echo $date;

 ?>
```

Comment: soooooo what is the question?

Comment: please show us error..

Answer (score 1):

The error is the querystring

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?date"+date,true);
                                  ^^^^
```

It missing the = between the name and the value, Add the = and the server will stop complaining that it does not know what date[DateString] is in the GET parameters

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?date="+date,true);
                                   ^
```

better yet to encode it

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?date="+encodeURIComponent(date),true);
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line and try again

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?date="+date,true);
```